# Can Transact-SQL detect functional dependencies automatically like MySQL?

Tags: mysql, t-sql

When I groupby certain columns, then SELECT other columns not appearing in GROUP BY, there will be the
`Column 'X' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` 
MySQL can detect functional dependencies: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html, but i'm unable to find any source specifying whether T-SQL can do the same?

Comment: That behaviour, from MySQL, is *not* standard and (in my honest opinion) should not be relied on. Define your groups properly with a `GROUP BY`, whether you're using MySQL or not.

Comment: MySQL doesn't. MySQL doesn't detect functional dependencies as much as *allows* non-grouping columns in the `SELECT` clause, resulting in rather unfortunate results. Performance can drop dramatically from one *minor* MySQL version to the next. Even for MySQL this is an "unsupported" feature which means Oracle doesn't feel obligated to ensure it's performant

Comment: Ideally, you should have the `only_full_group_by` (at least that's what my Google-fu tells me it's called) setting enabled when using MySQL; then it can't make use of the "feature". I believe the setting is enabled by default, which implies you're using an old version of MySQL or you intentionally turned it off; neither are recommended.